# How to find whether an input string provided is a valid charset or not?

Tags: python, character-encoding

Is there any way to check if the given string variable contains a valid charset name.

For Example:

input:

```
str = "utf-8"
#checking str, if valid charset name then return True

str= "abcd"
#checking str, if invalid charset name then return False
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Programming language Python.

Comment: Duplicate *10; But [here you go anyway](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/)

Comment: First thing. Please don't use str as variable name as it is a built in Python function.

Comment: @T.Woody thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question as wanting to validate that a string is a valid encoding name.  [codecs.lookup(encoding)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.lookup) can do that:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.lookup('utf-8')
<codecs.CodecInfo object for encoding utf-8 at 0x1e7c42905e8>
>>> codecs.lookup('abcd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: abcd
```

So you could use:

```
def validate(name):
    try:
        codecs.lookup(name)
        return True
    except LookupError:
        return False
```